# Задача на ruby. ООП. Калькулятор

Tags: ооп, ruby, наследование

Нету у кого спросить/узнать/получить подсказку, поэтому пишу тут...
Есть вот такие вот потуги написать определенный кейс, в **ruby** и **MVC** я совсем зеленый, поэтому прошу отнестись с пониманием к такому роду коду.

Задача состоит в том, что объект класса Handler должен содержать **ТОЛЬКО** публичные члены ***add_handler, calculate, print_out***.
 Он должен реализовать поведение :

> ```
> controller = HandlerController.new
> controller.add_handler(empty_handler)
> controller.add_handler(min_handler) 
> controller.add_handler(max_handler)
> ```

При вызове метода **calculator** с одним аргументом, производится вычисление над переданным массивом во всех переданных в контроллер объектах **handler**.

> ```
> controller.calculator([1,2,3,4,5])
> controller.print_out
> #Handler min return: 1
> #Handler max return: 5
> #Handler 'empty name' return "method is empty"
> ```

При вызове метода с двумя аргументами(вторым аргументом передается массив имен объектов) вычисляем только по объектам чье имя передано.

> ```
> controller.calculator([1,2,3],['min','max']) 
> controller.print_out
> ```

```
class Handler

        attr_reader :name

        def initialize(name='empty name')
            @name = name
        end

        def calculator(array)
            'Calculate method is empty'
        end

    end

    class HandlerController

        attr_reader :arr_operands

        def initialize
            @arr_operands = Array.new
        end

        def add_handler(operand)
            @arr_operands.push operand
        end

        def calculator(array)
            @arr_operands.each { |operand| puts operand }
        end

        def print_out # примерно так, наверное...
          puts "Handler" + arr_operands[name] + "return:" + arr_result[result]
        end
    end

    class MinHandler < Handler

    end

    class MaxHandler < Handler

    end

    class AverageHandler < Handler

    end

    class PremaxHandler < Handler

    end

    class SumHandler < Handler

    end



    empty_handler = Handler.new('max')
    max_handler   = MaxHandler.new
    min_handler   = MinHandler.new

    p empty_handler

    controller = HandlerController.new
    #p controller
    controller.add_handler(empty_handler)

    #p controller

    puts controller.arr_operands.name
    #puts empty_handler.name

    #puts controller.calculate([1,2,3])
```

Ткните меня в ошибки(или потенциальные ошибки) и подскажите как правильно реализовать, пожалуйста.
Можно было бы посмотреть реализацию на других языках. JavaScript например.

Comment: 1. Неразбериха с `calculate`. Иногда это `calculator`.

Comment: 2. Можно чуть подробнее про методы `calculate` и `print_out`? Первый считает и сохраняет результат в инстанс, второй выводит результат. Правильно?

Comment: Да, всё верно вы поняли) кстати я набросал вариант метода print_out и исправил имена calculate
Методы которые всё это дело вычисляют я написал, нужно только этот "интерфейс" правильно запилить.

Comment: такой Task, так что да, чтобы разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К слову, `HandlerController` реализует паттерн `Builder`.

По порядку.
1. Очень рекомендую ознакомиться ос [стайл-гайдами](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Есть вещи которые откровенно режут глаза (например такие `name='empty name'` (без пробелов))

2. > def initialize(name='empty name')

Не надо так. Лучше определить константу DEFAULT_NAME.

3. > attr_reader :arr_operands

Если тебе не нужно чтобы это смотрело куда-то наружу (например извне ты будешь получать операнды) то лучше убрать этот ридер вообще. Внутри класса обращайся к нему через `@arr_operands`. Инстанс - переменные работают быстрее чем геттеры.

4. > @arr_operands.each { |operand| puts operand }

Не понимаю как это должно работать. Фактически ты пытаешься делать вывод своих объектов класса `Handler`. Видимо, нужно хотябы `operand.calculate`.
Но вообще, тебе скорее всего нужно будет просто получать результат здесь (не уверен). Тогда правильнее будет вызвать `@arr_operands.map { |handler| handler.calculate(array) }`.

5. > def calculate(array)

У тебя по задаче должен быть второй аргумент. Правильнее тебе будет определить вложенный класс, который будет фильтровать и позволять итерироваться по массиву. Внутри него и обработаешь наличие или отсутсвтеие второго аргумента.

6. > print_out
   >   Это не очень рабочий код вроде.
   >   В любом случае, старайся делать классы, каждый из которых будет решать только одну задачу. Один - для хранения хендлеров, второй - для сохранения результатов, третий для вывода и т.д.

[Тут](https://gist.github.com/anoam/7e7b255e793ab00f2f1d) я набросал пример.
Работает так:

```
iterator = Iterator.new
repo = ResultReposytory.new
handler = Handler.new("Test Empty")
controller = HandlerController.new(iterator, repo, Printer)
controller.add_handler(handler)
controller.print_out
# => ""

controller.calculate!([1,2,3])
controller.print_out
#=> "Handler Test Empty return "

min_handler = MinHandler.new("minimum")
controller.add_handler(min_handler)
controller.print_out
# => "Handler Test Empty return "
"Handler minimum return 1"
```